# Matlab coder refline, num2str, rsmak and fnplt are not supported

Tags: c++, matlab

I am trying to convert a Matlab project into C++ by using Matlab coder. But when trying to build the project using Matlab coder, I get the following error.
[image: Errors]

> refline is not supported for code generation

```
hold on
draw_ellipse(ac,bc); hline = refline(0, li); hline.Color = 'r'; stra=num2str(li); str1={'li=' stra}; text(0,50,str1);
text(40,-50,'analytical uniaxial method')
hold off
```

> num2str is not supported for code generation

> rsmak is not supported for code generation

```
function[]=draw_ellipse(a,b)
t = linspace(0,2*pi); X = a*cos(t);
Y = b*sin(t);
plot(X,Y,'b-')
circle = rsmak('circle');fnplt(circle)
circle = rsmak('circle');fnplt(circle)
axis equal
```

> fnplt is not supported for code generation

Here is my full matlab [code](https://pastebin.com/7pHQ1Khq).

Is there an alternative to the functions for me to convert the project or any other workaround?

Comment: Matlab can convert calculation code into another language, but for all the high level graphic functions (`fnplt`,`refline` etc ...) which are supposed to draw on screen, Matlab cannot know which C++ graphic library you are using so it cannot convert that for you. I don't think you'll find alternative graphic functions in Matlab which can be translated. Your best bet is to split your code into 2 modules: (1) calculations, and (2) graphing. For (1) you can use the coder ... for (2) you'll have to code it directly in c++ yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to refer to the Matlab documentation, section [Supported Functions and Toolboxes](https://mathworks.com/help/coder/language-supported-for-code-generation.html). I'm pretty sure graphical objects are not in that list.

That 'solves' your first problem.

Then, num2str [does support C/C++ code generation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) (see 'extended capabilities' in the documentation). But it has a limitation: the input arguments must be constants. That **is** a limitation...

People have come up with various workarounds already, see this post: [Matlab coder num2str not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527248).

Hope that one of its answers is to your liking!